# Modify by parameter or return value

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, c++14

Say I have the following type aliases:

```
class window;
class context;

using window_handle = std::unique_ptr<window>;
using context_handle = std::unique_ptr<context>;
```

and some functions for making handles:

```
window_handle make_window(/* window parameters */);
context_handle make_context(/* context parameters */);
```

Then what would be the best practice for combining the context into the window?

(the `context_handle` variable will be unused after this operation)

---

*The possible solutions could be...*

Modify a reference parameter:

```
void attach_context(window_handle &w, context_handle &&c);
```

or return a combined handle that takes ownership of previous handles:

```
window_handle attach_context(window_handle &&w, context_handle &&c);
```

---

Both methods have merit and allow different uses.

One advantage of the return method could be inline window creation and removing explicit temporaries:

```
auto mywindow = attach_context(make_window(), make_context());
```

no need to create extra variables for `w` or `c`, rvalues are fine.

But then the lvalue-reference parameter method also has the advantage of not having to create a new variable or do an extra assignment when we already have a `window_handle`:

```
auto mywindow = make_window();

if(need_attached_window)
    attach_context(mywindow, make_context());
```

where with the return value method we have to use the `std::move` cast and an additional variable or assignment:

```
auto mywindow = make_window();

if(need_attached_window)
    mywindow = attach_context(std::move(mywindow), make_context());
```

All of this isn't taking into account that `make_xxx` could fail.

---

Which method should I prefer from a performance and usability standpoint? Which seems most idiomatic?

Comment: Since both approaches work, this comes down to personal preference, IMHO.

Comment: @RemyLebeau well, one approach will have better efficiency over the other in different situations... so not *really*. But I guess you could argue that it is.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to use a const-reference for the window and to pass the context by value. That way what is going on is explicit:

```
void attach_context(window_handle const& wh, context_handle ch);
```

Ownership to the context must be passed, and attach_context does not have the option of taking ownership of the window and passing something else back.

Update after clarification:

Given that `attach_context()` deallocates and creates a new `window` instance a const reference to the `window_handle` will not work. So the double rvalue-reference interface is probably preferable:

```
void attach_context(window_handle&& wh, context_handle&& ch);
```

Why rvalue-references over references? Avoiding non-const references in interfaces. This originates from Lakos's "Large Scale C++ Software Development" so you can see, at the calling site, whether a parameter will be modified or not. If you take an address (ie. non-const pointer) you know the parameter will be modified, otherwise the parameter is unchanged by the function. This advice is old (~1997) and predates rvalue references.

The presence of rvalue references gives obvious advantages. Using `std::move` or passing an rvalue reference at the call side makes it clear what is going on in the same way, meeting the same objective.

Comment: What benefit does passing `context_handle` by value have over rvalue-reference?

Comment: Oh, `attach_context` modifies the `window_handle` passed in; so it *must* be a non-`const` reference.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Did you try it? My reading of your requirement is that `attach_context` modifies the `window` instance, not the `std::unique_ptr<window>` instance. The function signature passes a const reference to a non-const pointer -- The `window` instance can be modified but the `unique_ptr` cannot.

Comment: I didn't try it because I can't :) The function modifies the handle **and** the object. It actually deallocates the `window` and sets the `window_handle` to point at a derived type.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Oh, I see. I didn't read that in your question. If you're creating and destroying the window, why not just create the right window in your `attach_context()` function?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode On the value vs. rvalue-reference for the other argument -- Not a huge advantage, in some ways rvalue references are better.

Comment: It does a little more than what I said, actually. It creates a new instance of a derived type of `window` then copies over any needed window manager handles from the original `window`, sets the original `window`s members to `0`, deallocates `window` then sets `window_handle` to point to the new derived type.